# This code transforms raw data in a table into nested objects

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a huge array that I want to group by by category and subcategory. A Book is contained in a shelf. A Shelf is contained in a Library. The output is a list of Library. I cannot change my Book class, but I am free to organize the Shelf and the Library class.How can I improve the grouping? Current running time is O(n) and I don't want to lose perf. I am more looking for a cleaner way to achieve the same result. How can I improve this code? To me, it seems a bit to *long* for a simple problem and I think I am missing something.

I don't control this one. I can add code but not remove a property:

```
class Book
{
    public int LibraryId {get;set;}
    public string LibraryName {get;set;}
    
    public int ShelfId {get;set;}
    public string ShelfName {get;set;}
    
    public int Cost {get;set;}
    public int Price {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ForeName {get;set;}
    public string Stuff {get;set;}
    
    public Book(int libraryId, string libraryName, int shelfId, string shelfName
                , int cost, int price, string name, string foreName, string stuff)
    {
        LibraryId = libraryId;
        LibraryName = libraryName;
        ShelfId = shelfId;
        ShelfName = shelfName;
        Cost = cost;
        Price = price;
        Name = name;
        ForeName = foreName;
        Stuff = stuff;
    }
}
```

Here we can do whatever we want:

```
class Library
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Cost {get;set;}
    public int Price {get;set;}
    public List<Shelf> Shelves {get;set;}
    
    public Library (Shelf shelf)
    {
        Id = shelf.Books[0].LibraryId;
        Name = shelf.Books[0].LibraryName;
        Cost = shelf.Cost;
        Price = shelf.Price;
        Shelves = new List<Shelf> {shelf};
    }
}

class Shelf
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Cost {get;set;}
    public int Price {get;set;}
    public List<Book> Books {get;set;}
    
    public Shelf (Book book)
    {
        Id = book.ShelfId;
        Name = book.ShelfName;
        Cost = book.Cost;
        Price = book.Price;
        Books = new List<Book> {book};
    }
}
```

The table is a SQL table with around 5000 rows right know. With real data is quantity is unknown but should be higher:. The table is already ordered by Library then by Shelf:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var table = new[] {
        new Book (1, "Green", 42, "A", 10, 1, "Gra", "Bar", "etc."),
        new Book (1, "Green", 43, "B", 21, 2, "Grb", "Bar", "etc."),
        new Book (2, "Blue", 652, "C", 10, 1, "Blc", "Bar", "etc."),
        new Book (2, "Blue", 652, "C", 01, 7, "Bl2", "Bar", "etc."),
        new Book (2, "Blue", 123, "D", 12, 4, "Bld", "Bar", "etc."),
        new Book (8, "White", 94, "E", 14, 9, "Foo", "Bar", "etc."),
        new Book (9, "Grey", 142, "F", 11, 6, "Foo", "Bar", "etc."),
        new Book (9, "Grey", 142, "F", 12, 2, "Bar", "Bar", "etc.")
    };
```

Here we walk the table (**This is the part I would like to improve**):

```
    var libraries = new List<Library> { new Library (new Shelf(table[0])) };
    foreach (var item in table.Skip(1))
    {
        if (item.LibraryId != libraries.Last().Id)
        {
            libraries.Add(new Library(new Shelf(item)));
            continue;
        }
        
        if (item.ShelfId != libraries.Last().Shelves.Last().Id)
        {
            libraries.Last().Cost += item.Cost;
            libraries.Last().Price += item.Price;
            libraries.Last().Shelves.Add(new Shelf(item));
            continue;
        }
        
        libraries.Last().Shelves.Last().Cost += item.Cost;
        libraries.Last().Cost += item.Cost;
        libraries.Last().Shelves.Last().Price += item.Price;
        libraries.Last().Price += item.Price;
        libraries.Last().Shelves.Last().Books.Add(item);
    }
    var totalCost = libraries.Sum(x => x.Cost);
    var totalPrice = libraries.Sum(x => x.Price);
```

I dont know how to use xUnit.Net or NUnit on .NETFiddle so...

```
    Console.WriteLine(libraries.Count() == table.Select(x => x.LibraryId).Distinct().Count());
    Console.WriteLine(total == 91);
    
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Name == "Green");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves.Count() == 2);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[0].Name == "A");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[0].Books.Count() == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[0].Books[0].Name == "Gra");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[1].Name == "B");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[1].Books.Count() == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[1].Books[0].Name == "Grb");

    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[0].Books.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 10);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[1].Books.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 21);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[0].Cost == 10);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves[1].Cost == 21);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Shelves.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 31);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[0].Cost == 31);

    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Name == "Blue");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves.Count() == 2);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[0].Name == "C");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[0].Books.Count() == 2);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[0].Books[0].Name == "Blc");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[0].Name == "C");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[0].Books[1].Name == "Bl2");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[1].Name == "D");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[1].Books.Count() == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[1].Books[0].Name == "Bld");
    
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[0].Books.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 11);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[1].Books.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 12);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[0].Cost == 11);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves[1].Cost == 12);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Shelves.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 23);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[1].Cost == 23);

    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Name == "White");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Shelves.Count() == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Shelves[0].Name == "E");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Shelves[0].Books.Count() == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Shelves[0].Books[0].Name == "Foo");
    
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Shelves[0].Books.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 14);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Shelves[0].Cost == 14);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Shelves.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 14); 
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[2].Cost == 14);     
            
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Name == "Grey");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves.Count() == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves[0].Name == "F");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves[0].Books.Count() == 2);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves[0].Books[0].Name == "Foo");
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves[0].Books[1].Name == "Bar");
    
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves[0].Books.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 23);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves[0].Cost == 23);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Shelves.Sum(x => x.Cost) == 23);
    Console.WriteLine(libraries[3].Cost == 23); 
}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/diow2O)

Comment: How can I improve the quality of the question?

Comment: It's not my DV but I'm not happy about this part: _I dont know how to use xUnit.Net or NUnit on .NETFiddle so..._ - you don't have to post an example that works on .netfiddle but instead you should share your real code where you use xUnit. Reviewing someting that you actually don't use is pointless.

Comment: @t3chb0t I mean I am not looking for a review of the test. I add them if someone wants to play with the code to check if there is no error.

Comment: Is this loop exactly the same as in your actual code?

Comment: @t3chb0t yes. The main difference is that I have two kind of cost with the same logic in my code and a dozen of other (useless) property in Book. I trimmed then to showcase the problem.

Comment: That's too bad. Reviews about such code usually are commented with _oh, I actually have that but removed it from the code to simplify it_ - this kind of reviews don't help anyone - don't worry about the couple of _useless_ properties - _lengthy_ but real code is worth much more than any shortened version.

Comment: @t3chb0t Ok I will add them later :)

Comment: @t3chb0t, the console.Writelines look like working tests that are not using xUnit, the reasoning is because they don't know xUnit so they are writing Writelines instead.  The Tests are for reviewers benefit.

Comment: I know xUnit.net, but I do not know a fiddler like .netfiddle or tio who include a tdd library online for C#. I could have set a Travis or Appveyor but it would have be overkill for this script. 'The Tests are for reviewers benefit.' <- Yes :)

Comment: How are you getting the data?  Are you receiving only the array?  Are your building the array from a `DataTable`?  Is the array being mapped directly fron the SQL query?  This will influence how your code can be made better.

Comment: @tinstaafl I get the array from a SQL query.

Comment: @BCdotWEB fixed. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do away with the extra classes since each book has the information needed.  A nested `groupby` query will give you the exact groupings that you want:

```
var libraryGroups = (from Book b in table
               group b by b.LibraryId into libraries
               from shelves in
               (from b in libraries
                group b by b.ShelveId into shelves
                select shelves)
               group shelves by libraries.Key);
```

To print out all the data 3 nested loops will be needed:

```
foreach(var library in libraryGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Library Name = {library.First().First().LibraryName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Shelf Count = {library.Count()}");
    var totalCost = 0;
    foreach(var shelf in library)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Shelf Name = {shelf.First().ShelveName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Book Count = {shelf.Count()}");
        foreach(var book in shelf)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(book.Name);
        }
        int shelfCost = shelf.Sum(x => x.Cost);
        Console.WriteLine($"Shelf Cost = {shelfCost}\n");
        totalCost += shelfCost;              
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Library Cost = {totalCost}\n");
}
```

To print a subset of the data adjust which loops are used.

Once your main query has been made, you can filter and or aggregate the result however is needed.

the print out for this looks like this:

```
Library Name = Green
Shelf Count = 2
Shelf Name = A
Book Count = 1
Gra
Shelf Cost = 10

Shelf Name = B
Book Count = 1
Grb
Shelf Cost = 21

Library Cost = 31

Library Name = Blue
Shelf Count = 2
Shelf Name = C
Book Count = 2
Blc
Bl2
Shelf Cost = 11

Shelf Name = D
Book Count = 1
Bld
Shelf Cost = 12

Library Cost = 23

Library Name = White
Shelf Count = 1
Shelf Name = E
Book Count = 1
Foo
Shelf Cost = 14

Library Cost = 14

Library Name = Grey
Shelf Count = 1
Shelf Name = F
Book Count = 2
Foo
Bar
Shelf Cost = 23

Library Cost = 23
```

Comment: Are you sure this query works? There is no `select` statement at the end.

Comment: @t3chb0t - Yes. It works. The print out is a copy and paste from the console after it's been run.  When there's no `into` clause the `group` clause doesn't need the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing your code a couple things jumped out...

1. The objects have no methods. They are what I would call "data bags". One OOP principle I generally stick to is, "Let the objects do the work".
2. Incrementing cost and price while looping works, but we can also store the book data and sum it as necessary via LINQ.

I admire @tinstaafl's answer... short, sweet, and highly effective use of LINQ, which taught me something new about nested queries. Thank you.

While I appreciate the concentrated power of things like `library.First().First().LibraryName` I thought it might be nice to make the object model more domain-oriented and explicit.

Below is my general take on how I would solve this problem by relying on objects' methods rather than external manipulation of their data.

The LibraryChain class is the "container" for all the Libraries. It encapsulates everything, which allows the App_Library.Run() method to do be 3 lines.

Since Library and Shelf have the same Id and Name properties, I based them on the abstract Container class. We could take this abstraction further, but I didn't want to complicate things.

For good measure I added the IAccountable interface to identify all classes on which we'll be calculating sums. And, I played with the output format a bit...

If you do ever get the chance to modify the Book class, could replace LibraryId and LibraryName with a Library, and ShelveId and ShelveName with a Shelf.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Forums
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int LibraryId { get; set; }
        public string LibraryName { get; set; }

        public int ShelveId { get; set; }
        public string ShelveName { get; set; }

        public int Cost { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ForeName { get; set; }
        public string Stuff { get; set; }

        public Book(int libraryId, string libraryName, int shelveId, string shelveName
                    , int cost, int price, string name, string foreName, string stuff)
        {
            LibraryId = libraryId;
            LibraryName = libraryName;
            ShelveId = shelveId;
            ShelveName = shelveName;
            Cost = cost;
            Price = price;
            Name = name;
            ForeName = foreName;
            Stuff = stuff;
        }
    }

    public interface IAccountable
    {
        int Cost { get; }
        int Price { get; }
    }

    public class LibraryChain : IAccountable
    {
        private List<Book> books;

        public List<Library> Libraries { get; private set; } = new List<Library>();
        public bool LibraryExists(int id) => Libraries.Where(l => l.Id == id).Any();
        public Library Library(int id) => Libraries.Where(l => l.Id == id).First();
        public int Cost => Libraries.Sum(l => l.Cost);
        public int Price => Libraries.Sum(l => l.Price);

        public LibraryChain(List<Book> books)
        {
            this.books = books;
        }

        public void Parse()
        {
            books.ForEach(b =>
            {
                Library library;
                if (!LibraryExists(b.LibraryId))
                {
                    library = new Library(b.LibraryId, b.LibraryName);
                    Libraries.Add(library);
                }
                else
                {
                    library = Library(b.LibraryId);
                }

                Shelf shelf;
                if (!library.ShelfExists(b.ShelveId))
                {
                    shelf = new Shelf(b.ShelveId, b.ShelveName);
                    library.Add(shelf);
                }
                else
                {
                    shelf = library.Shelf(b.ShelveId);
                }

                shelf.Add(b);
            });
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine($"All Libraries Report");
            sb.AppendLine($"Total Cost = {Cost}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Total Price = {Price}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Library Count = {Libraries.Count}");
            sb.AppendLine();
            Libraries.ForEach(l => sb.AppendLine(l.ToString()));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Container 
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public Container(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }        
    }

    public class Library : Container, IAccountable
    {
        public List<Shelf> Shelves { get; set; } = new List<Shelf>();
        public bool ShelfExists(int id) => Shelves.Where(l => l.Id == id).Any();
        public Shelf Shelf(int id) => Shelves.Where(l => l.Id == id).First();
        public int Cost => Shelves.Sum(s => s.Cost);
        public int Price => Shelves.Sum(s => s.Price);

        public Library(int id, string name) : base(id, name)
        {
        }

        public void Add(Shelf shelf)
        {
            Shelves.Add(shelf);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine($"Library {Id}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Name = {Name}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Cost = {Cost}");
            sb.AppendLine($"Shelf Count = {Shelves.Count} ");
            sb.AppendLine($"Shelves:");
            Shelves.ForEach(s => sb.AppendLine(s.ToString()));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Shelf : Container, IAccountable
    {
        public List<Book> Books { get; private set; } = new List<Book>();
        public int Cost => Books.Sum(b => b.Cost);
        public int Price => Books.Sum(b => b.Price);

        public Shelf(int id, string name) : base(id, name)
        {
        }

        public void Add(Book book)
        {
            Books.Add(book);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine($"\tShelf {Id}");
            sb.AppendLine($"\tName = {Name}");
            sb.AppendLine($"\tCost = {Cost}");
            sb.AppendLine($"\tBook Count = {Books.Count}");
            sb.AppendLine($"\tBooks:");
            Books.ForEach(b => sb.AppendLine($"\t\t{b.Name}"));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class App_Library
    {
        private LibraryChain getLibraryChain()
        {
            var list = new List<Book> {
                new Book (1, "Green", 42, "A", 10, 1, "Gra", "Bar", "etc."),
                new Book (1, "Green", 43, "B", 21, 2, "Grb", "Bar", "etc."),
                new Book (2, "Blue", 652, "C", 10, 1, "Blc", "Bar", "etc."),
                new Book (2, "Blue", 652, "C", 01, 7, "Bl2", "Bar", "etc."),
                new Book (2, "Blue", 123, "D", 12, 4, "Bld", "Bar", "etc."),
                new Book (8, "White", 94, "E", 14, 9, "Foo", "Bar", "etc."),
                new Book (9, "Grey", 142, "F", 11, 6, "Foo", "Bar", "etc."),
                new Book (9, "Grey", 142, "F", 12, 2, "Bar", "Bar", "etc.")
            };
            return new LibraryChain(list);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var chain = getLibraryChain();
            chain.Parse();
            Console.WriteLine(chain.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

To Run:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new App_Library();
    app.Run();
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress <Enter> to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
All Libraries Report
Total Cost = 91
Total Price = 32
Library Count = 4

Library 1
Name = Green
Cost = 31
Shelf Count = 2
Shelves:
        Shelf 42
        Name = A
        Cost = 10
        Book Count = 1
        Books:
                Gra

        Shelf 43
        Name = B
        Cost = 21
        Book Count = 1
        Books:
                Grb


Library 2
Name = Blue
Cost = 23
Shelf Count = 2
Shelves:
        Shelf 652
        Name = C
        Cost = 11
        Book Count = 2
        Books:
                Blc
                Bl2

        Shelf 123
        Name = D
        Cost = 12
        Book Count = 1
        Books:
                Bld


Library 8
Name = White
Cost = 14
Shelf Count = 1
Shelves:
        Shelf 94
        Name = E
        Cost = 14
        Book Count = 1
        Books:
                Foo


Library 9
Name = Grey
Cost = 23
Shelf Count = 1
Shelves:
        Shelf 142
        Name = F
        Cost = 23
        Book Count = 2
        Books:
                Foo
                Bar




Press <Enter> to continue...
```